How to add files to Confluence Cloud using Python?
In a directory, there are .md (Markdown) and .jpg files.
I need to add them to Confluence Cloud.
This is an ongoing task, NOT a onetime task.
I want to use Python programming for this.
The .md and .jpg files should be copied as is. I don't want to lose any formatting from markdown files.
I appreciate your help!
